# Simulink delay block doesn't recognize vectors as intial conditions

Tags: matlab, kalman-filters, simulink, probability, programming

I am trying to implement the kalman filter on simulink, for which I need the delay block to compute the new estimate based on the previous one. My state vector is three dimensional, and for some reason simulink fail to specify its dimension. I wrote my intial condition as [0;0;0]. I am not sure, if this is the proper way to do it. As you see in the screenshot below, the dimension of the covariance-matrix P gets recognized flawlessly.

[image: Simulink recognize matrix dimensions, however doesn't recognize vectors]

Comment: Simulink does seem to know the input dimensions of your delay block. Since the output needs to match the input, that's why there's a ? On the output dimension

Comment: Its a loop, so it suppose to know the next output based on the intial condition of the delay block.

Comment: The initial conditions dimensions must also match the input dimensions.

You can also force the output dimensions.